# Breakup cable bill responsibility

Tags: united-states, billing

My son's girlfriend had cable setup for internet in the house they were renting in her name.  They broke up and she moved out in December of last year and did nothing with the cable company.  My son does not use the internet and now his ex is telling him he owes her $280 for the cable bill.  She is taking him to small claims court.  He is nowhere on the bill and does not use the service.  Is he responsible for the bill?

Comment: Have him offer half to settle.  $140 is  a cheap way to learn a valuable lesson.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice.

Comment: `My son does not use the internet` - He just had it for 3 months and didn't use it? Sounds unlikely

Answer (score 9):

This is a legal question, really.

If the bill was in her name and if they had no agreement about this, it's fairly clear-cut that it is the ex-girlfriend's responsibility.

Small claims court generally uses a standard of 'reasonableness', so the judgment can go in either direction. Your son needs to be very clear he expected the ex to cancel the cable once she moved out, that they didn't agree he'd take over the bills, and, critically important, that he made absolutely zero use of the service since she moved out.

If it turns out that he made occasional use of the Internet service, he'd all but certainly be responsible for the entire bill.

Comment: If it was in her name how could he even cancel it?

Comment: He couldn't; I said "he expected the ex to cancel the cable".

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on your jurisdiction, but generally small claims court is a court of fairness.  You'll each present your side of the story to the judge who is generally just a lawyer volunteering.  Then the "judge" will decide what's fair.

I'd just settle with the ex to pay half of it and move on with life. It seems reasonable that your son is at least half liable because he didn't ensure the service was cancelled.